# Swift 3: Data saved in File gets lost on switching between Simulators iPhone 5s and 6s, 6s Plus

Tags: ios, xcode7, swift3

I am saving user registration data in a File using

```
NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject
```

With iPhone 5S selected in the Simulator, when the registered member logs in, I am validating the user using

```
NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile
```

The validation is successful, and user is able to login.

However if I switch to iPhone 6s or 6S Plus simulator, and use the same credentials, the validation is unsuccessful and user cannot login

I was hoping switching between simulators should not impact the data-storage or retrieval functionality, anybody experience similar issues with Swift 3 (Xcode 7.3) ?

Comment: not sure why the downvote though. I didn't find any apple documentation around it even after spending about 2.5 hours and hence asked it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour and it has always been like this.  The different simulators are just like different physical devices.

If you had two phones and you ran your app on one, you wouldn't expect the same data to be on both devices in the absence of some data synchronisation, such as iCloud.  It is the same with the simulators.

Answer (score 2):

That's how it works. Each simulated device has its own simulated sandbox in which to store files. If you look in `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/` you'll see an entry for each simulated device.